# Xpath - Need the locator for Gmail's email body to read the message sent

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, gmail

Using Selenium, I am trying to read the response body of a specific email. I have navigated to the email I desire. I just cannot seem to find a static locator to grab as the class/id is dynamically allocated.

Anyone have a xpath that will allow me to read the text of any gmail body?

Answer (score 1):

Posting my own answer, I discovered an xpath that works to for locating: 
Gmail > recieved email > Response Body

```
//div[@class='ii gt ']//div[contains(text(),'**Insert your recognizable email text here**')]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like message body is the element with class `'ii gt '`, so try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ii.gt")).getText()
```

But better option is to read messages via [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list).